# Winning probability

Tags: probability

What is the probability of a player A to win a multiplayer tournament with three other players B, C and D? Given ELO ratings A-2200, B-2100, C-2000, D-1900 A should have a probability of 64 %, 76 %, 85 % to win against those other players.

But the probability of winning the tournament is *not* 0,64 * 0,76 * 0,85 = 41 %, is it, because that doesn't match up:

A 41 % - B 18 % - C 6 % - D 1 % = 66 % in total.Should be 100 %.

Is there a better formula for the total probability in this case?

Comment: Does every player play one game against the others? Also, when does one win the tournament?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be $100\%$. The way you're calculating the probability of winning the tournament is correct (for four players) if a) each pair of players plays exactly one game, b) each game is either a win or a loss and c) a player wins the tournament by winning more games than any other player. In this case, there is a considerable probability that there is no winner since two or more player have the same number of wins.

Comment: Good point. Also the question "when does one win the tournament" was a good one. By Multiplayer tournament I mean for instance a football league that is won by having scored more points than all other teams when the season is ended. So you obviously will not win the tournament only by winning all games... But is there a formula in this case?